# How to interact with a smart contract with ethers.js?

Tags: solidity, web3js, etherscan, ethereumjs, ethers.js

I need a general-purpose method to call functions from a smart contract using ethers.js. I've always used web3 and I'm trying to transition over; however, I cannot find any good examples of calling functions in ethers.js.

Here is an example:

Let's say I want to transfer my bored ape to another wallet. In etherscan I can easily call the write-only function:
https://etherscan.io/token/0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d#writeContract
[image]

If I want to call the same function in ethers.js I know I need something like this, but I would kill for a good example.

```
var ethers = require("ethers");

const abi = <bayc abi here>;
var url = "your-quicknode-here"
var customWsProvider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(url);
let contractAddress = "0xBC4CA0EdA7647A8aB7C2061c2E118A18a936f13D";
let contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, customWsProvider);
let privateKey = 'your-privatekey-here';
let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, customWsProvider);
console.log("wallet connected for purchasing...")

wallet.sendTransaction???
```

Comment: provider url and wallet private key should be stored in a ".env" file they would be then connected to "hardhat.config.js".  Then you can separate connection to contract and contract call parts.

Answer (score 1):

```
 const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, tokenAbi, connection);
const transaction = await tokenContract.balanceOf(put address here)
const data = Promise.resolve(transaction)
data.then(value => {
    const result = ethers.utils.formatUnits(value, 18);
    console.log(result)

});
```

To make a change

```
 const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, tokenAbi, connection);
var signer = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, connection);
const txSigner= tokenContract.connect(signer);
const transaction = await txSigner.transfer(to,address,amount)
const data = Promise.resolve(transaction)
data.then(value => {

    console.log(value)

});
```